# after editing the urlpatterns in the urls.py file on django, the local server (127.0.0.1:8000) stopped working - I get a 404 (not found) message

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and trying to figure out how the basics work here.

I created a new project and received a local server IP, when I go to it, it works just fine (gives me the default message signifying that all is working well).

BUT -

when I go to urls.py in the my main directory and try adding another url, suddenly it stops working all together, i.e. it doesn't even recognize the original IP, let alone the new addition.

Here's the original code that works fine (I added the "include" import, but this didn't bother the program from running properly):

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and if I simply add another line to the list (for simplicity I just copied the first one.. I tried other things though and got the same result), like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And now when I look at my IP address, it gives me a 404 message:

[screen shot of the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er8Cl.png)

NOTE:
I've encountered this problem when trying to specify other urls, it seems as if I'm following the tutorials precisely and in those examples this working method runs just fine.. For me it doesn't. Any ideas? What am I missing? Thanks! Iddo

Comment: There's no matching url configured in your app for 127.0.0.1:8000. Try  127.0.0.1:8000/admin.

Comment: Thanks for answering..

Comment: Thanks for answering.. Here's what I don't get - if I don't add that second line, I can go to 127.0.0.1:8000 just fine. Why does adding a second item in the list suddenly make it "forget" how to do what it did a second before? to make this clearer, I added a url with a random name and tried going there, but it still didn't work.. Any idea what this might be?